# python - comparing a newly written file with filecmp.cmp() always returns False?

Tags: python

I must be making a stupid mistake here, because this *should* be working. I'm thinking the file is staying open or something, and it's driving me nuts.

This is for some regression test cases I have where I'm comparing generated output of a script ran against mock files to known good output files (key files).

Here is a simple example:

```
def run_and_compare(self, key_file, out_file, option):
    print filecmp.cmp(out_file, key_file) # always True (as long as I've run this before, so the out_file exists already)
    cmd = './analyze_files.py -f option'
    with open(out_file, 'wb') as out:
        subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=out, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print filecmp.cmp(out_file, key_file) # always False 
    time.sleep(5)
    print filecmp.cmp(out_file, key_file) # always True
```

I really don't want to keep that sleep in the test! How can I be sure the out file is OK to compare without using the sleep? I've tried using out.close(), but it doesn't work, and shouldn't be needed as long as I'm using 'with'. I'm using python 2.6.4 if that matters here.

Comment: `filecomp.cmp()` caches outcomes, so the *first* `True` you see is cached from the last time you called this function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter that you opened the output file object as a context manager. It wouldn't even matter if you explicitly, manually closed the file object.

That's because when you hand a Python file object to `subprocess.Popen()`, all it takes from that file object is the *file handle*, an integer number that your OS uses to communicate about open files. The subprocess then uses [`os.dup2()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup2) to clone that filehandle onto the STDOUT file handle of a child process; this is what causes the output of that child process to go to your designated file on disk.

Because the file handle is duped, closing the original Python file object (and indirectly, the original OS file handle) won't *actually* close the file, because that second file handle still keeps it open.

The reason that you see the file data appear after waiting a few seconds, is because eventually the subprocess you created will complete and *only then* is that other, duped file handle closed.

Instead of waiting for a few seconds, wait for the subprocess to complete using the [`Popen.communicate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=open(out_file, 'wb'),
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()  # stdout will always be None
```

I inlined the `open()` call, because there is no other use for that file object once `subprocess.Popen()` retrieved the file handle from it. You could also use `os.open()` instead of `open()` (same arguments) and safe yourself creating a Python file object where only a file handle is enough.

Don't use `p.wait()`; because you are using a *pipe* for the STDERR stream of the child process, you can deadlock the process if you *don't read* from STDERR but the child process writes a lot of data to it. You'd end up waiting forever.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you add a `wait` to your subprocess to wait for it to complete

```
with open(out_file, 'wb') as out:
    p=subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=out, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
```

If you don't wait, the subprocess starts, taking the file `out` as output and returns immediately (starts in background).
When you compare both files, one is probably empty hence the False.

After a while, the subprocess ends, `out` is no longer used and probably garbage collected, handle closed: your file is valid.
(I'm not saying it is exactly what's going on here, but the lack of `p.wait()` is surely the issue here)

Aside from that, I have always wondered why people run subprocesses involving python commands when it's so simple to import them and call their functions directly, thus benefiting from exception chain, one sole process, avoiding all this inter-process communication issues..

Comment: This is correct; I was debugging and found that the output file was smaller (empty, in fact). The only reason for it to be smaller is if there is still data being written to it; here, by the pipe.

Comment: Thanks, makes total sense. I'm relatively new to python, but will look into importing commands and calling functions directly.

Comment: the `with open` construction in that case is a false guarantee that the file will be closed when getting out of scope in that case. If one of the python gurus could confirm that would be great.

Comment: Specifically, `subprocess.Popen()` takes the file handle to create a pipe and [duplicates that handle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup2); that Python closes the Python file object doesn't mean anything to the file handle; the OS handles that level and keeps the file open until the pipe is done. Put differently: it is out of the hands of the file object to close the file; it does its best (as far as the file object is concerned, things are closed), but it is really `subprocess` and the OS that now manage the lifetime.

Comment: I've expanded this into an answer explaining *why* this all happens. Also, you should really use `p.communicate()`, even if the `stderr` is to be ignored otherwise. You can deadlock the process waiting but not reading.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: Using `stderr=Subprocess.STDOUT` would avoid the deadlock too right?